# Google Plus iOS SDK: how to get logged in user email?

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-plus

Currently playing around with GooglePlusSample with scope:

```
@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", 
@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" and 
@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile".
```

Tried calling `auth.userEmail`, auth.userData in callback method `finishedWithAuth:error:`, but both are empty...

Comment: have you solved this? I've encountered the same situation...

Comment: Not yet. The project is still on the development and this feature was suspended. Currently we just show username.

Answer (score 11):

```
-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Received Error %@  and auth object==%@",error,auth);

    if (error) {
        // Do some error handling here.
    } else {
    [self refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn];

    NSLog(@"email %@ ",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email: %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail]);
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);

    // 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

    // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
    [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];


    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

    // *4. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.*
    plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";

    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {



                    //Handle Error

                } else
                {


                    NSLog(@"Email= %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
                    NSLog(@"GoogleID=%@",person.identifier);
                    NSLog(@"User Name=%@",[person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",person.name.familyName]);
                    NSLog(@"Gender=%@",person.gender);

                }
            }];
    }

}
```

Comment: Christ thank you for this... Couldn't for the life of me figure out how to get the person's name *without* using google plus.

Comment: thank, but I still have the email null. Is there any other alternative ?

Answer (score 4):

Once user is authenticated you can call `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] userEmail]` to get authenticated user's email.

Comment: You need to set `[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES` to access that property, otherwise it will give you `nil`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

Firstly use the userinfo.email scope as per :

```
signInButton.scope = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      kGTLAuthScopePlusMe,
                      kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail,
                      nil];
```

Then define these methods :

```
- (GTLServicePlus *)plusService {  
  static GTLServicePlus* service = nil;  
  if (!service) {
    service = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
    // Have the service object set tickets to retry temporary error conditions
    // automatically
    service.retryEnabled = YES;
    // Have the service object set tickets to automatically fetch additional
    // pages of feeds when the feed's maxResult value is less than the number
    // of items in the feed
    service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
  }
  return service;
}

- (void)fetchUserProfile {
  // Make a batch for fetching both the user's profile and the activity feed
  GTLQueryPlus *profileQuery = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
  profileQuery.fields = @"id,emails,image,name,displayName";
  profileQuery.completionBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
      // Get the user profile
      GTLPlusPerson *userProfile = object;
      // Get what we want
      NSArray * userEmails = userProfile.emails;
      NSString * email = ((GTLPlusPersonEmailsItem *)[userEmails objectAtIndex:0]).value;
      NSString * name = userProfile.displayName;
      NSString * profileId = userProfile.identifier;
    } else {
      // Log the error
      NSLog(@"Error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
  };

  GTLBatchQuery *batchQuery = [GTLBatchQuery batchQuery];
  [batchQuery addQuery:profileQuery];
  GTLServicePlus *service = self.plusService;
  self.profileTicket = [service executeQuery:batchQuery
                           completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                               id result, NSError *error) {
                             self.profileTicket = nil;
                             // Update profile
                           }];
}
```

And finally call the "fetchUserProfile" method in the "finishedWithAuth" as per :

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
{
  // An error?
  if (error != nil) {
    // Log
  } else {
    // Set auth into the app delegate
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.auth = auth;  
    // Get user profile
    self.plusService.authorizer = auth;
    [self fetchUserProfile];
  }
}
```

Note this may not be perfect as it's a 'work in progress', in particular re: getting the correct email address when the user has more than one but it's a start!

Good luck.
Steve

Comment: Thanks, but I'v already tried this but I'm receiving the error (see below) in profileQuery completion block. I have triple checked - Google+ API is enabled in console and client code is correct (though I can login and do posting with existing values). Here's an error: "Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured)" UserInfo=0x6af0150 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Access Not Configured), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x893d470: {message:"Access Not Configured" code:403 data:[1]}, error=Access Not Configured}"

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access not configured error check services in google api console. make sure you enable google plus api services.